# Why do I get a "Uncaught TypeError" when I introduce a D3 .transition()?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working with the D3-pack-Layout. Everything is going well, I even added transitions when I click on a button. Now I also want to add a transition at the very beginning. I want my Bubbles to fly in at the beginning. Before I introduce that transition, the code looks like this and works fine:

```
d3.csv("myData.csv", function(error, data) {
dataset = data;
generateVis();
});

function generateVis() {

var pack = d3.layout.pack()
    .sort(function(a, b) {
        return b.Order1 - a.Order1;
    })
    .size([width,height])
    .value(function(d) { return d.value; })
    .padding(5);

var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(pack.nodes({children: dataset}).slice(1))
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", function(d) { return d.children ? "node" : "leaf node"; })
    .attr("transform", function(d){return "translate("+d.x+","+d.y+")";})
    .attr("r",function(d) {return d.r;})
    .attr("class", "hover")
    .attr("myX", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("myY", function(d) { return d.y; });
}
```

**If I add a transition, I get "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function". Why is that?** The code look like this:

```
d3.csv("myData.csv", function(error, data) {
dataset = data;
generateVis();
});

function generateVis() {

var pack = d3.layout.pack()
    .sort(function(a, b) {
        return b.Order1 - a.Order1;
    })
    .size([width,height])
    .value(function(d) { return d.value; })
    .padding(5);

var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(pack.nodes({children: dataset}).slice(1))
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("class", function(d) { return d.children ? "node" : "leaf node"; })
    .attr("transform", function(d){return "translate("+d.x+","+d.y+")";})
    .attr("r",function(d) {return d.r;})
    .attr("class", "hover")
    .attr("myX", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("myY", function(d) { return d.y; });
}
```

Comment: Tested your code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/QHHxmBYPMOfW6frt5nFm?p=preview), it works.  One thing I don't see in above is where you cast your csv string values into numeric values.

Comment: Hi Mark! Thanks for the comment. I'm one step further. I think the problem is caused by the .on
See this plank: http://plnkr.co/edit/uz7ikbtItG5et19iM8xC?p=preview
The Tooltip works when there is no transition. As soon as there is a transition, the tooltip doesn't work and I get the error.

Answer (score 0):

In your tooltip code, you are calling `.on` on the transition object.  It has no `on` method hence:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

It's important to remember that in method chaining you are acting on the last thing in the chain to return something.

Your problem is easily solved by moving the `.on` to before the `.transition`, since you want to call it on the `.append` selection.

```
.append("circle")
.on("mouseover", function(d) {
    ...
})
.transition()
...
```

Updated [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/fKzR03eKawC4i3nD3Xqt?p=preview).